# Getting Connection timeout in OCCI

Tags: c++, database, oracle, connection

I need to test the connectivity if the Oracle::OCCI::Connection, and how can i get and set the connection timeout value? i read the documentation of Oracle OCCI but i can't find the required functions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this document: http://www.terralib.org/html/v410/classoracle_1_1occi_1_1_connection_pool.html

Here you can see

- virtual unsigned int     getTimeOut () const =0
- and
- virtual void     setTimeOut (unsigned int connTimeOut=0)=0

functions.

Answer (score 1):

This answer refers to `setTimeout()` function of `oracle::occi::ConnectionPool` class, not the `Oracle::OCCI::Connection`.
This function sets a timeout for disconnecting an idle pool connections, not a connect timeout.

But I don't know the real answer...